# Deliver file according to user ID

Tags: web-apps, google-apps, google-drive

I would like to know if there is some kind of software or add-on (preferably for Google Apps) that I can use to deliver different files according to someone's ID.

For example, in some sort of page, someone is asked his ID number. After it is inputted, a download of a specific file starts just for that user.

Any idea how to do this? I would like to avoid sending hundreds of different e-mails for each individual user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a document management system with some rules applied to an action / task / folder? 
1 - [Alfresco community edition](https://www.alfresco.com/alfresco-community-download)
2 - [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com/products/content-management-platform/) 

to name but two.

Comment: Alfresco seems to have what I need, thanks :)